# Using Multicam Editing How to Color Correct an entire angle

Tags: premiere, color-correction

Am new to Premier CS6 - working with Multicam editing.  Having success but stuck on color correction.  I am able to create a multicam clip and do my edits using the Multicam Editing window (very slick and fast).  Also able to adjust those edits in the timeline to improve timing.  Sweet.

*How do I color correct (or add an effect) to an entire angle in a multicam sequence after I've applied the edits (or even before)?*

If I drag the effect into the timeline it sticks only to a particular edit and won't get to all the edits from that angle.  I can't drag it into the upper-left window ("browser"?) and don't know how else to apply the effect.

I've read some online but am hitting a wall with how I get to the underlying video footage behind the multicam edit.

Can someone hold my hand and guide me?

#### Detail Steps Taken in CS6

1. Place video files (angles) in the project browser
2. For each file, double click to preview video and then set corresponding in-points
3. Select all video angles in project browser, right-click, and choose *Make multicamera clip...* (by in-point)
4. Place new multicam clip in the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all is correct you enable the multi camera mode on a sequence containing the different angles in different tracks as shown in the image below (this is CS5.5, but CS6 is similar).
  The image shows a sequence containing 4 different clips which represent 4 different angles.
In this example these are just a collection of random footage, but it works the same if you have actual different footage from different angles.

[image]

Let's call this `Sequence 01`. Now put `Sequence 01` in another sequence,

[image]

click on `Multi-Camera -> Enable` and then you can switch witch camera you want in `Sequence 02`.

[image]

**According to the information in your question you've already come so far.**

Now if you want to color correct one angle (lets take the angle called `Leaf.MOV`) just open `Sequence 01`, apply the effect to the clip (drag and drop on the `Leaf.MOV` clip) and this changes should propagate into your multi-cam edits.

Please feel free to ask any question if this doesn't work for you. I'll try to help.

Comment: Your approach works; I added detailed steps to my question to see how our approaches differed.  I didn't put all the clips in their own sequence first -- I just set in-points and then created a multicam clip from the project browser.  Your instructions, though, seem to work great! Thanks

Comment: Good to hear it works, I was not aware of your method. Consider accepting my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Accepted! I clicked on it twice as the answer already but wasn't sticking ... I think it stuck this time.